# WebRTC - is it possible to have a browser proxy video from a source to a receiver?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

For example:

- Browser A is broadcasting video
- Browser B is a middle man
- Browser C is receiving the video

Is it possible to do something like this where browser B acts as an intermediary between A and C?

Secondly, would it be possible for B to both view the broadcasted video from A *and* forward it on to C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure this works fine. (Use [https fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLq5qr5h/) for Chrome):

```js
function Hop() {
  this.pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection();
  this.pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection();

  var add = (pc, can) => can && pc.addIceCandidate(can).catch(log);
  this.pc1.onicecandidate = e => add(this.pc2, e.candidate);
  this.pc2.onicecandidate = e => add(this.pc1, e.candidate);
  this.pc2.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => log(this.pc2.iceConnectionState);
};
Hop.prototype.send = function(stream) {
  this.pc1.addStream(stream);
  return Promise.all([
    new Promise(resolve => this.pc2.onaddstream = resolve),
    this.pc1.createOffer()
      .then(offer => this.pc1.setLocalDescription(offer))
      .then(() => this.pc2.setRemoteDescription(this.pc1.localDescription))
      .then(() => this.pc2.createAnswer())
      .then(answer => this.pc2.setLocalDescription(answer))
      .then(() => this.pc1.setRemoteDescription(this.pc2.localDescription))
  ])
  .then(results => results[0].stream);
};

var AtoB = new Hop(), BtoC = new Hop();

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
  .then(stream => AtoB.send(v1.srcObject = stream))
  .then(stream => BtoC.send(v2.srcObject = stream))
  .then(stream => v3.srcObject = stream)
  .catch(e => log(e));

var log = msg => div.innerHTML += msg + "<br>";
```

```html
<video id="v1" height="120" width="160" autoplay muted></video>
<video id="v2" height="120" width="160" autoplay></video>
<video id="v3" height="120" width="160" autoplay></video><br>
<div id="div"></div>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

You can create as many hops as you like.

Comment: jib, we have a sample for that as well :-)
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple-relay/

Comment: Why does the quality degrade? Is it being reencoded or are packets dropped?

Comment: we are allowed to transmit remote streams?, damnit, never knew that